# How to run a python script in Java program using Docker container?

Tags: java, python, docker

i am new to docker and trying to dockerize a java app, which in turn calls a python script

Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ARG SCRIPT_FILE=src/main/resources/script/test.py

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY ${SCRIPT_FILE} test.py
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Now my App has a line of code which executes a python script, something like this :
Code snippet :

```
        String interpretor = "python";
        String scriptFile = "test.py";
        String arguments = "ping";
        String[] cmd = {interpretor,scriptFile,arguments};
        
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            ...
```

**Exception:**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python runtime does not exist in the base image `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`, you need to install it first before calling python script.

You can try below

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ARG SCRIPT_FILE=src/main/resources/script/test.py
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY ${SCRIPT_FILE} test.py
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```